# Asynchronous call fired from synchronous call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

Using jQuery's AJAX function, I am doing a synchronous call to a PHP script (it runs a shell command to convert a video).

I am trying to use "beforeSend" to run a different asynchronous AJAX call that will read a text file every second (to find out the conversion progress of the video) but it seems that despite the 2nd call being async, it doesn't run asynchronously, instead only being called after the first sync call has finished.

Is there a way to have the async task carry on, as it should, when being ran from the firsts "beforeSend" option?

I understand a sync task locks up operations, but surely this way of using "beforeSend" should work?

Comment: It is impossible to have an asynch call running at the same time as a synchronous one. Do not use a synchronous call.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to get around something, and it was a stab in the dark. Clearly doesn't work, so I'll try something else :)

Answer (score 0):

beforeSend is for modifieng the xhr object (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), not for this kind of stuff

you could try to run a selfcalling timout function in beforeSend() and then handle the conversion progress logic there.

Comment: however, that won't help in any way toward keeping the async request running while the sync one is.

Comment: Send the response to the second call when the first one is done? On the server side you should know the processing state